# Discord API - random "invalid code" error passing back generated OAuth2 code

Tags: oauth-2.0, discord

I've successfully implemented Discord's OAuth2 flow using the authorization code grant type into my application. The end user navigates to Discord's OAuth2 link for my bot, authorizes its access, and Discord redirects them back to my site with a `code` querystring. The bot then exchanges this code for an access token by querying Discord's API. Documentation on this process is available [here](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2) for reference.

However, **roughly every 50-100 requests to the exchange endpoint, I receive a 403 with the error `invalid_grant` and the description `Invalid "code" in request.`** Frankly, I don't understand how the code just provided by Discord's system is instantly invalid. The same user can complete the process again and no error is returned the second time.

Out of desperation, I tried toggling on the option in the Developers Dashboard named `Requires OAuth2 Code Grant` seeing that it said "if your application requires multiple scopes," but it made no effect. I've also tried endless debugging, but the circumstances under each occurrence are apparently random. Oddly enough, I can't find anyone with the same issue online.

Below is the request I'm making in Node.js using the [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) library. It matches the documentation and works perfectly, other than the response randomly being the error described.

```js
superagent.post('https://discordapp.com/api/v6/oauth2/token')
  .type('x-www-form-urlencoded')
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
  .send({
    client_id: process.env.BOT_ID,
    client_secret: process.env.BOT_SECRET,
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    code,
    redirect_uri: process.env.OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI,
    scope: 'identify guilds.join',
  });
```

I can confirm that all variables match their expected values. The value of `redirect_uri` matches that of `redirect_uri` in the original URL used. `code` is the value of the `code` querystring returned through the OAuth2 flow.

What (if anything) am I doing wrong that's causing the error?

---

**Update 1:**

Discord has directed me to the API GitHub repo, and I found the issue closed [here](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/982). Commented and will update here if I receive any helpful info or resolve the issue completely (hopefully the case).

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue using nodejs. Leaving here notes for prosperity:

- On Node, if there is no explicit app.head() handler, the .post() handler receives all head requests
- Several Android phones, upon being redirected from discord, first send a head request to the endpoint

Meaning:

- The user authenticates on discord, then through the redirect back, does a head request. This pulls discord with the code, BUT directly afterwards it also does a post request, which will fail (as you already used the code once), and possibly un-authenticates the user.

Solution for my specific issue was an explicit .head handler for all callback endpoints, which basically just returned the same headers (a redirect) as the post one did, but without calling discord.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I believe I'm having this same issue with a user having troubles logging in, but I'm running simple cURL requests through PHP. I'm trying to wrap my head around the nodejs terminology, but I'm having difficulty, would you be able to help me understand your answer in PHP terms?

Comment: PHP has framework-specific HEAD, and POST request handling -check your framework's docs. Point here is to make sure, that a user pathway of HEAD /login?authcode=xxxxxxx + POST /login?authcode=xxxxxxx   <- still succeeds.

Comment: I appreciate the response! I was definitely overcomplicating it in my head at first, but I was able to figure it out by detecting if the $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'HEAD' then simply die(); before anything else was parsed or sent.

Answer (score 0):

did you use the OAuth2 link to invite your bot to your server - with the correct permissions? If so, in your main.js file did you define the token?
I.e. bot.login(“YOUR_TOKEN_HERE”)
I would recommend not toggling the ‘Requires OAuth2 Code Grant’ as it is a pain to do anything with in the beginning.
Please let me know of any progress :)

Comment: The bot isn't being added to a server (I'm not using the `bot` scope). Although there isn't a need to instantiate and log in a client, the token (which is required for the API instead) does indeed match. When an invalid token is provided, an "Unauthorized" error is returned which is different than what I'm encountering. And I agree, that option is a total pain, so I already disabled it.

Comment: Apologies, I am completely inexperienced in this field and am unable to suggest any further solutions - I do hope this is solved. Gl